# How to make few column's initially hidden with col-toggler data table primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

Suppose, I have a column array as follows:

```
this.cols = [
{field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'},
{field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
{field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
{field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
];
```

and I want two column's vin and brand to show on initial load, and year and color to be hidden.
All the column's need to be there in the col-toggler with vin and brand as checked and year and color as unchecked

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: yes I found the solution, but I had to modify the col-toggler code. There is 'hidden' property in p-column of p-datatable, you can go in that direction

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove the columns you don't want, and add them when you want them.

Comment: I want all the column's to be there in the col-toggler with few as checked and few as unchecked

Comment: Columns or rows ? I have no knowledge of columns being checked